# Fore ground image for Layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

Hi I am working with the project which needs user details like Firstname, Lastname, Phone, Email etc.I used Linear layout, In a linear layout I set background and there is textview and edittext for each user detail. While entering the user details that should be like this.

[image]

When I click to see the user details that should be like this.

[image]

please tell how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the background of your EditText to null ?
Also for the "First Name" text inside the EditText, use the property:

```
android:hint="First Name"
```

This should of course take the string from your strings.xml file for easy translation.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have different ways to achieve this.
But one really simple approach is:
You can place a textview and an edittext.
When you want the editText to appear you set its visibility to visible and the visibility of the textview to gone and vice versa.

Simple and effective.

Comment: Hi that was a good idea, but I am expecting make the edittext as non edittable and the linear layout's background as its foreground like that. Please tell me any other way.

Comment: Ah i misunderstood the question. So to be clear, you want the textbox look like an editext (transparent background, solid text, non-editable). when not editing the details?

Comment: When I click the button, The edittext box border should need to gone and look like a textview also the linearlayout's background image should come foreground like second image.